# Field for bounded real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

On page 12 of Luenberger's Optimization by Vector Space Methods, he claims that the set of bounded real sequences is vector space with addition defined component-wise.

Ok, but what is the underlying field? $\mathbb{R}$? But then for a given $K$, you can always find a large enough $M(K)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $M(K)\left(x_i\right)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ becomes unbounded ($\exists i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert M(K)x_i\rvert > K$)  and so is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Thinking naively, if it is not possible to pick an arbitrarily large scalar, then it should also not be possible to *ever* construct an unbounded real sequence (as the components of the sequence and the field are the same set, $\mathbb{R}$).

As is probably evident, my knowledge of analysis is rudimentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused about "the set of bounded real sequences".  It doesn't mean the set of real sequences bounded by some given bound $K$, but the set of *all* real sequences bounded by *some* bound, which may be different for each sequence.

That is, we're not talking about the set

$$S_K = \{(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}\ |\ \forall i \in \mathbb N: -K \le x_i \le K\},$$

for some given $K$, but about the set

$$S = \{(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}\ |\ \exists K \in \mathbb R: \forall i \in \mathbb N: -K \le x_i \le K\} = \bigcup_{K \in \mathbb R} S_K.$$

It's easy to see that $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  In particular, note that a sequence belongs to $S$ if and only if it belongs to $S_K$ for some $K \in \mathbb R$.

Thus, if $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ belongs to $S$, it belongs to $S_K$ for some $K \in \mathbb R$.  Therefore, for any $a \in \mathbb R$, $a(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ belongs to $S_J$, where $J = |a|K$, and thus to $S$.

Similarly, if $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in S_K$ and $(y_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in S_J$, then $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} + (y_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in S_{K+J} \subset S$.

Comment: Thanks Ilmari. Ok, but then I can have $K(\left(x_i\right))$ as the bound for an individual sequence, and choose arbitrarily large $M(K(\left(x_i\right)))$ that makes that sequence unbounded. I think my confusion is that I am tending to think of $\mathbb{R}$ as $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, but without this, I cannot see how unbounded sequences can result (that is by picking components from $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Praetoria: I'm not quite sure what you mean by $K((x_i))$ above, but I edited my answer to include an explicit proof that $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  I hope it clarifies things.

Comment: It does to some extent. $K(\left(x_i\right))$ simply denotes the sequence dependent finite bound - same as in your definition.
I am just wondering why it cannot be that the $a$ cannot be picked large enough (depending on the sequence dependent bound) so as to make the sequence unbounded - given that we have access to the entire real line.
For this, I understand that you cannot make a finite number ($K$) non-finite by multiplying by an element of $\mathbb{R}$, but by that same token, I do not understand how you can get an unbounded sequence when picking all components from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think my last comment shows my ignorance of analysis - I suppose unbounded sequences are an asymptotic phenomena - and no _one_ element is "$\infty$".

Comment: @Praetoria: Yes.  A simple example of an unbounded sequence is $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$, $x_i = i$.  You should find it easy to verify that all the elements of the sequence are finite, but that the sequence surpasses every finite bound.